# Validation under array validation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

If I have an array validation rule, how can I check if all the items in the array is a valid email? I'm using this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-array for the array validation rule.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|array.email'
]);
```

Note: I'm using laravel 5.1 version

**Update** - as per request.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

checked is validate:

> above 5.2

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'email.*' => 'required|array|email'
],[
    'email.required' => 'message required',
    'email.array' => 'message array',
    'email.email' => 'message email',
]);
```

OR

> Less than 5.2

```
    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'array',

        /* Other rules */

    ],[
        'email.required' => 'message required',
        'email.array' => 'message array',
        'email.email' => 'message email',
    ]);

    $validator->each('email', 'required|email');

    if($validator->fails()) 
        return back()->withErrors($validator->errors());


    dd('Success All Email ;)');
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. I'm using laravel 5.1 version.

Comment: @Jonjie Have you tested?

Comment: Nice. Can you also include the link for `$validator->each('email', 'required|email');`?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5645#issuecomment-68328399 | https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5645#issuecomment-68362955

Comment: This works fine. Alright, one more thing. How can I customize the message for the email validation rule?

Comment: @Jonjie I'm not sure of the second one, but check it out

Answer (score 1):

You need custom validator. In Laravel Request you can do something like that

```
public function __construct() {
    Validator::extend("emails", function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        $rules = [
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ];
        foreach ($value as $email) {
            $data = [
                'email' => $email
            ];
            $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
}

public function rules() {
    return [
        'email' => 'required|emails'
    ];
}
```

Or

Validating Arrays laravel 5.2 onwards :

Validating array form input fields doesn't have to be a pain. For example, to validate that each e-mail in a given array input field is unique, you may do the following:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'person.*.email' => 'email|unique:users',
    'person.*.first_name' => 'required_with:person.*.last_name',
]);
```

Likewise, you may use the * character when specifying your validation messages in your language files, making it a breeze to use a single validation message for array based fields:

```
'custom' => [
    'person.*.email' => [
        'unique' => 'Each person must have a unique e-mail address',
    ]
],
```

Hope this helps you.